# Max and Min value in array

Tags: c

My program is giving me two minimum values and no maximum values. My program is supposed to print max value if opcode is 1 and min value if opcode is 0. Help please

```
#include <stdio.h>

int minmax(int array[], int array_size, int opcode);

int main(void)
{
    int array[]= {99,4,95,2,98}; //array size
    int array_size = 5;
    int i;
    int opcode;
    array_size = 5;
    for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i , array[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter an opcode 0 or 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &opcode);
    minmax(array, array_size, opcode);
}

int minmax(int array[], int array_size, int opcode)
{
    int i;
    int max = array[0];
    int min = array[0];
    for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        if (opcode == 1 && array[i] > max)
        {
            max = array[i];
            printf("The max value is: %d\n", max);
        }
        else if (opcode == 0 && array[i] < min)
        {
            min = array[i];
            printf("The min value is: %d\n", min);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not print the maximum because the first element itself is the maximum.

That is,

```
if (opcode == 1 && array[i] > max)
{
max = array[i];
printf("The max value is: %d\n", max);
}
```

never executes in this code.

The remedy to be output the minimum or maximum **at the end** of the `minmax()` function.

Your code should look like:

```
int minmax(int array[], int array_size, int opcode)
{
int i;
int max = array[0];
int min = array[0];
for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
if (opcode == 1 && array[i] > max)
{
max = array[i];
printf("The max value is: %d\n", max);
}
else if (opcode == 0 && array[i] < min)
{
min = array[i];
printf("The min value is: %d\n", min);
}
}
//The below code prints the final max / min (as determined by opcode)
if (opcode == 1) printf("The final maximum is %d\n",max);
else printf("The final minimum is %d\n",min);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AdarshMangina If it helped, please accept the answer. Just click the tick below the upvote downvote answer. Thanks.